# Cartoon featuring a blonde action heroine and dinosaur

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, dinosaurs

Please help me identify the name of a '90s or early 2000s cartoon.

The woman is white, blonde, attractive and tough looking. Her hairstyle is in a ponytail, but might be armified like a jarhead. The dinosaur is like a T-Rex, but not much bigger than her, and I think he's green. I think both can speak. I think one or possibly both are cybernetically enhanced.

Their adventures take them all over the place, but I think it's set in the future. It's an action series and also at times the cartoon can be kinda visceral. In my mind, the animation is of pretty good quality and never dull, so I'd say it's possibly mid '90s earliest.

Portals might have been involved. Lastly, not to throw anyone off, and I'm not sure about this, but the title may feature one or more of the words 'trip/ping', 'void,' 'rift,' or none of them. Anyway, it's not "*Tripping the Rift*" or "*Void Trip*".

Comment: In roughly which year did you actually watch this?

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Comment: Understood thank you

Comment: I watched it in 1996 till it's end.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is this ***[Project G.e.e.K.e.R.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_G.e.e.K.e.R.)*** (1996–1997)...?

> The show parodied the style of action-adventure cartoons. Set in the future, it was based around a genetic shapeshifter experiment known as Project GKR (Geno-Kinetic Research), who had been stolen by Lady MacBeth (a short-tempered cyborg with a bionic arm) before the creator could finish programming. He needed to be a deadly and powerful weapon at the hands of the evil Mister Moloch, head of Moloch Industries, but due to the lack of his final programming, "GeeKeR" is left to be a totally random, permanently salivating, four-fingered klutz. He only occasionally manages to use his powers to any full extent, a blessing and a threat to his friends and their enemies. Lady MacBeth (whom GeeKeR calls Becky) and her partner-in-crime Noah, a baseball cap-wearing intelligent Tyrannosaurus rex, must now prevent Moloch and GeeKeR's creator Dr. Maston from ever obtaining GeeKeR at all costs.

The main characters are a blonde, ponytailed cyborg woman named Lady MacBeth and an intelligent T-Rex called Noah, and the story is set in the future, which lines up with your description.

Comment: That voice is pretty famous. Billy West from Futurama fame as the voice of Geeker. lol

Comment: By Jove you've done it! Horay! I needn't have waited a week. Sorry. Holy moly I can't believe it. THANK YOU. It's cooler than I remembered but also quite different. I guess my 7 yo brain had it's vision. I am forever in your debt. I love this site.

Comment: It wasn't just some weird fever dream, it actually existed. Can't tell who exactly answered the question.. thanks again. That's the show for sure

Comment: @LocalVoid - I answered the question. Thanks for marking it as accepted and confirming that it's correct. You can tell who posted an answer by looking at the username near the bottom-right corner of that answer. Sometimes, an answer may have been edited by another user, in which case their username will appear near the bottom-middle. That doesn't apply here, though.

Comment: Okay I see. Thanks